# error tuning custom algorithm with caret r

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I want to tune two parameters of my custom algorithm with caret. Un parameter (lambda) is numeric and the other parameter (prior) is character. This parameter can take two values "known" or "unknown". I've tuned the algorithm with just the lambda parameter. It's okay. But when I add the character parameter (prior) gives me the following error:

> 1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :   model fit failed for Resample01:
>   lambda=1, prior=unknown Error in mdp(Class = y, data = x, lambda =
>   param$lambda, prior = param$prior,  :    object 'assignment' not found

the error must be related with the way to specify the character parameter (prior). Here is my code:

```
my_mod$parameters <- data.frame(
  parameter = c("lambda","prior"),
  class = c("numeric", "character"),
  label = c("sample_length", "prior_type"))

## The grid Element

my_mod$grid <- function(x, y, len = NULL){expand.grid(lambda=1:2,prior=c("unknown", "known"))}

mygrid<-expand.grid(lambda=1:2,prior=c('unknown','known'))


## The fit Element

my_mod$fit <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...){ 
  mdp(Class=y,data=x,lambda=param$lambda,prior=param$prior,info.pred ="yes")
}

## The predict Element

mdpPred <- function(modelFit, newdata, preProc = NULL, submodels = NULL)
  predict.mdp(modelFit, newdata)
my_mod$predict <- mdpPred

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5,repeats = 5)

train(x=data, y = factor(Class),method = my_mod,trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = mygrid)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would work, could you please check if `method="my_mod"` i.e. with quotes. Because in the docuementation of `train()` and `trainControl()`, they have used quotes for method inside `train`. Also, please specify what you `my_mod` had originally, i.e. before adding parameters, pred, fit, etc.

Comment: Is it classification or regression?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian Classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you must specify `as.character(param$prior)` in the fit function.